# PowerShell Script to detect ADUser Changes before synching to Office365

Tags: powershell, ad

Office365 - OneDrive for Business is sending out some alerts to managers of colleagues advising that their content is going to be deleted as they're leaving.  Nothing is visible in the tenancy setting and on our synched AD farm these accounts aren't marked as disabled nor are they deleted.

I'd like to see if anything has changed on the accounts in question recently and wondering if I can pull up a list of account changes via PowerShell.  If so, how would I get this done?

Thanks
Steven